# Is LaTeX open source?

Tags: latex-project, licensing

I know that LaTeX is free. But is it open source? Is it possible to obtain the source code for LaTeX? From what I understand TeX is open source. Are the macros that make up LaTeX open source?

Comment: "LaTeX" is a set of macros that builds on the so-called TeX primitives; nothing there to be *compiled*. Are you asking if pdfTeX, XeTeX, and LuaTeX -- three main TeX "engines" these days -- are open source?

Comment: @Mico:Ahh.. yes. Ok, I guess I mean whether the macros are open source.

Comment: @Thomas: The core of LaTeX is fully defined in `latex.ltx`, readable (and sometimes understandable) and the documented in `source2e.pdf`. Since `LaTeX` is build on top of `TeX` it's Open Source. This might not be true for any package, if there's a special license.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Ok. I think I just realized my question is kinda trivial.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer "(and sometimes understandable)" is beautiful! :-)

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: Thanks ... hm... only 22 to be a trusted user ;-) And now it's 20008 -- I can trust you finally :-P

Comment: @ChristianHupfer :-)

Comment: More like "occasionally understandable."

Comment: Wikipedia exists: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX_Project_Public_License

Comment: Maybe , I'm mistaken but normally `free` is used not as in freeware or free beer but as in freedom (in contrast to unfree or propitiatory software) and open source is just a developing model.

Comment: No discussion on this is complete without a link to Frank's _TUGboat_: https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-1/tb100mitt.pdf

Comment: Define "open source", please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend you read up on `The LaTeX project public license` (LPPL), which may be accessed from http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/. Here's an excerpt from that site:

> The LaTeX project public license is a free software license. The most recent version of the LPPL is version 1.3c. The latest version, in plain text, can always be found at https://latex-project.org/lppl.txt. There is also a LaTeX version of the license, which authors of LPPL software are encouraged to include in their manuals.

Comment: And to it can be considered as "open source", right?

Comment: @Thomas - Please provide your definition of 'open source'. My understanding is that this term isn't unambiguous.

Comment: @Mico: I think Thomas means: Open Source →change the code (completely) such that nobody can sue you?

Comment: I don't really have a definition. I guess I just mean the source is available and can be changed? (What is the most common definition?)

Comment: @Thomas - The LPPL does have some restrictions. For instance, "You may distribute a complete, unmodified copy of the Work as you received it. Distribution of only part of the Work is considered
modification of the Work, and no right to distribute such a Derived
Work may be assumed under the terms of this clause." And, "If you are not the Current Maintainer of the Work, you may modify your copy of the Work, thus creating a Derived Work based on the Work, and compile this Derived Work, thus creating a Compiled Work based on the Derived Work." Key take-away: You can modify *copies*.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for clearification. I personally had no inclination to inject my 'inventions' to latex.ltx etc;-)

Comment: @Mico: Thank you for this. This was very helpful.

Comment: @Thomas LPPL is considered an open source licence by Debian (who are very strict about these things)  (most of the changes in the current version 1,3 of the LPPL were specifically to remove some concerns raised on Debian-legal)

Comment: I don't think that would count as 'open source' under any standard definition. The key point is that you can also *distribute* a modified copy. However, there are restrictions. In particular, your modified version must not claim to be the unmodified one: it must clearly tell the system that it is modified. Early versions of the LPPL were not considered free by EFF. I believe that the current version of the LPPL is considered a free licence by both EFF and Debian.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX_Project_Public_License) has a good discussion of the renaming/modification notice requirement and why this is accepted as free software by Debian, FSF, and OSI, but not "copyleft" per GPL compatibility.

Comment: @Thomas: Both OSI and FSF have accepted it as "open source" and "free software".

Comment: @cfr, you can distribute modified versions. Just not under the original name. This is explicitly allowed by OSI (in part to accomodate TeX, I presume).

Comment: @vonbrand That was my point.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on @Mico's answer: TeX and (base) LaTeX are just a (small) part of the hundreds of macro packages and programs that make up a LaTeX installation, like MikTeX or TeXlive. Each piece is under it's own license, mostly LPPL, but there is stuff under other licenses. The vast majority is under free/open licenses, but you'd have to check each piece to know for sure (or trust, e.g., TeXlive or your Linux distribution to have done due diligence).

Comment: It's worth adding that vitually all packages distributed via TeXLive satisfy either the LPPL or some other "free/open" license, such as the MIT style license. Some interesting packages, however, do *not* meet these licensing criteria; they may be found on the CTAN even though they (by design) cannot be distributed via TeXLive.

Answer (score 6):

About the open source, I think we can listen to the FSF (Free Software Fundation) and [licenses and comment about them](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html):

> LaTeX Project Public License 1.3a (#LPPL-1.3a)
>
> We have not written a full analysis of this license, but it is a free  software license,
>   with less stringent requirements on
>   distribution than LPPL 1.2 (described next). It is still incompatible
>   with the GPL because some modified versions must include a copy of or
>   pointer to an unmodified version.

They considered it as as a free licence with incompatibility with some other free licenses that are more restrictive.

Furthermore, as said before, some parts use in some LaTeX distribution are under other licenses as GPL/LGPL for example.

**Edit:**

Thanks to @JosephWright I add the [open source initiave](http://opensource.org/licenses/alphabetical) point of vue:

LPPL is one license that satisfies the requirements to be defined as Open Source by the open source initiative. You can access to every of those licenses in the link given.

Comment: Note that in this context 'free' and 'open' tend to be separate terms: the FSF are interested in freedom in an intellectual sense, which is not the same as the way the Open Source Initiative think about things. (In particular, I'd note that the FSF place a strong emphasis on freedom for the _programmer/developer_.)

Comment: @JosephWright I've modified my answer to add the OSI part thanks for pointing that `;-)`